# Disable Automatic Monitor Configuration

Tags: 10.04, gnome, ati, xrandr

Currently I have three monitors configured in an AMD Eyefinity setup with the Radeon HD 6670, which works well. Unfortunately, whenever one of monitors enters standby mode (or is turned off) my other monitors enter `Cloned desktop mode`, and have to be reconfigured to my `One large desktop` setup in amdcccle.

Since I need to be able to turn off my monitors to get rid of the annoying blinking blue lights, I can't avoid the monitors being removed from my display setup.

I've also noticed that if I turn off all of my monitors, Xorg will use 100% of my CPU, and will become unresponsive (even to the point where I cannot kill it). The only way to unlock my machine is to reboot.

Is it possible to disable automatic monitor detection so that changes are not made when monitors become unavailable to the system?

Comment: Odd - I don't have that. Are you using the proprietary drivers?

Comment: @jrg Yes, I am using the proprietary drivers (version 11.12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For users using the gnome2 desktop environment: Choose `System -> Preferences -> Power Management` and set `put display to sleep` to `never`. This will address the issue with Xorg using 100% CPU and allows you to turn off your monitors.

Answer (score -2):

Try [disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/). It might help you.